# TrayIcon into JFrame, is possible?

Tags: swing, jframe, trayicon

I do not want to reinvent the wheel, so I'd like to know if exist some component of notification, like TrayIcon, that I can set the location. Example: When I click over a button, show the notification beside the button, into my project.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you think of something like validation markers like this: http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/validationdemo/index.html ?

Comment: It's not possible. I need to show this notification, like a tool tip, but with appearence tray icon, and with close button :(

Comment: Ah, you are not thinking about the tray icon itself but about the notification popup that appears _above_ the tray icon?

Comment: Yes!  I've been searching on internet and I found this: http://balloontip.java.net/ . I will try using it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The library you found yourself looks nice. If you want to construct something similar yourself you need to use `JWindow` as base class; it is a top level window like `JFrame` but without borders. You just need to position it relative to your component. To get the screen position of a component you would use `SwingUtilities#convertPointToScreen`. Then you can just design as you want and use standard components and layout managers.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll try it myself. Thank you for your attention.